# JPA query to obtain entities based on child rows

Tags: jpa

I have a simple schema - Order and OrderState, with the latter recording how the state of an order has changed over time. The current state is that of the child row with the most recent timestamp.I need to query for all Orders with a given state. Both tables have an id column that is generated from a sequence, so the highest id for a given order is the current state.

So something like

`select order from Order o, OrderState os where os.order_id = o.id and os.id and os.state = <desired state> and os.id = *the highest id for that particular order*`

Im completely stumped...

Comment: try to add the mapping files / classes

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this 
**select * from Order o, OrderState os where os.order_id = o.id  and os.state ='desired state' order by o.id desc**

Comment: Not quite - as this will also retreive orders that at a point in the past had that state, but whose current state might be something different.

Comment: In the above query we are getting records based on desired state.In this case how you will get old records.Most recent timestamp only your current state means u will get exact result.If this is not correct can you provide more information regarding this